# How to make universal generic view for tables?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, helper, view-helpers

I want to make a view helper method for tables where I can pass any object and header object and it will easily map the headers and data in database and create a table.
I want to make it generic so I can use it anywhere in the project.
I tried to make using content_tag but was't successful enough.
I saw lot of answers on stack overflow but nothing fulfilled my interest.

Any help is appreciated.
This is something i tried to make which is specifically for Attachment model.

```
 def display_doc_table(columns, collection = {})

   thead = content_tag :thead do
     content_tag :tr do
      columns.collect {|column|  concat content_tag(:th,column[:display_name])}.join().html_safe
     end
   end

   tbody = content_tag :tbody do
    collection.collect { |elem|
      if elem.is_visible_to_all or (can? :manage, Attachment) 
        content_tag :tr do
          columns.collect { |column|
              concat content_tag(:td, link_to(elem.attributes[column[:name]], elem.document.url, data: { :colorbox => true, :colorbox_height => '700px', :colorbox_width => '700px', :colorbox_iframe => true }) , class: "remove_underline")
              concat content_tag(:td, link_to("Edit ",edit_attachment_path(elem)))
              concat content_tag(:td,"|")
              concat content_tag(:td, link_to(" Delete",attachment_path(elem), data: {method: :delete, confirm: "Are you sure?"}))        
      }.to_s.html_safe
    end
  end
    }.join().html_safe
   end

   content_tag :table, thead.concat(tbody)

end
```

However I wanted something like I will pass @header which will contain hash and @docs or @user i.e object of model.
where it will check if the there is action url in model if yes it will append the action to @header and will proceed further bu creating a column called Action which will have defined action url like edit and delete else it will just display table data as per @header.

something like this:

```
def table_for(@header, @user)
 if object has action url in it then
   append the action to header
create a table data as per header along with column Action or
just create a table data as per header.  
end
```

Thank You!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a full-featured approach, there are gems available (like [datagrid](https://github.com/bogdan/datagrid)) which can take care of both what you describe and additional functionality like sorting, filtering, etc. Unless you have a good reason to re-invent the wheel, I'd suggest looking into those alternatives (Google "rails data tables" or something similar).

For a bare-bones approach, you can leverage ActiveRecord's reflection abilities:

```
def table_for(relation, columns = relation.columns.map(&:name))      
  headers = columns.map(&:titleize).map {|h| "<th>#{h}</th>"}
  header_row = "<tr>#{headers.join}</tr>"

  rows = relation.all.map do |row|
    cells = columns.map {|attr| row.send(attr)}.map {|v| "<td>#{v}</td>"}
    "<tr>#{cells.join}</tr>"
  end

  "<table>#{[ header_row, rows ].flatten.join('\n')}</table>"
end

# view.html.erb

<%= h table_for(User) %>
```

But as you can tell, that's very basic and not very useful in any production context.